# How to configure TinyMCE to allow a block-level elements inside anchor tags?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, wysiwyg

Here is my scenario; I want to be able to create content like:

```
<div class="a">
    <a href="someurl"><img src="somepic"></a>
</div>
```

However TinyMCE strips it to

```
<div class="a">
    <img src="somepic">
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this with:

```js
{
 convert_urls : false,
 remove_script_host : false,
 verify_html: false,
 valid_children : "+a[div|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|p|#text]",
}
```

:)